# Prove that the stopping time is finite

Tags: probability, probability-theory, martingales, stopping-times

> Let $Y_0 = 0$ and $(Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0}$ be an iid sequence of random variables with zero mean and attaining exactly values in $\{1, 0, -1\}$ with positive probability. Consider the filtration $F^Y$ generated by $Y = (Y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0}$ . Define the process $X = (X_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}_0}$ via $X_n = \sum_{k=0}^n Y_k$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$. Moreover, define $\tau = \inf \{n \in \mathbb{N}:X_n = 1\}$, which is a stopping time corresponding to $F^Y$. Is $\tau$ finite?

This is an exercise I need to solve. Intuitionally, I think it is not true. I found a similar topic here ([Martingale: Show $p\{T<+\infty \}=1$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1329041/martingale-show-p-t-infty-1?rq=1)), but the definition of $\tau$ in that topic is different, and that difference enables us to conclude from the equation $()−(+1)=(−1)−()$ and $(−)=()=1$ that $u(i) = 1$ for all i. In this situation, we only have $u(1) = 1$, so we cannot use the same reasoning to conclude that. Can anyone give me some hint on how to solve this?

Comment: $\tau <\infty$ a.s iff $EY_n <0$ iff $P(Y_n=1) <P(Y_n=-1)$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: Can you explain further why?

Comment: $(X_n)$ is random walk on the integers and recurrenec/transience of it are well known facts. I am assuming familiarity with random walks.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that, I haven't learned about random walk. I hope there is a more elementary approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $p=P[Y_n=1] = P[Y_n=-1]$ (equal because $E[Y_n]=0$), and $r=P[Y_n=0]$ for $n\ge 1$. Clearly $2p+r=1$. Let $b:=P[\tau<\infty]$. By conditioning on the first step of the walk you see that
$$
b = p+rb+pb^2.
$$
That is, because $1-r = 2p$, $b$ solves the quadratic
$$
pb^2-2pb+p=0.
$$